# Real analytic function in one point and zeros

Tags: real-analysis, analyticity

Let $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $t_0\in I$ such that $f$ is analytic at $t_0$ and $f(t_0)=0$. Is it true that there is an entire neighbourhood of $t_0$ in which $f$ has no other zeros, excepting $t_0$?

Comment: Yes, is a particular case of the complex case: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Zeroes_of_Analytic_Function_are_Isolated.

Comment: Of course, you need to assume that, for each neighborhood $U$ of $t_0$, $f \not\equiv 0$ in $U$.

Comment: But, is it true that $f$ is analytic on a neighbourhood of $t_0$?

Comment: Yes. "Analytic at $t_0$" means the function is represented by a power series with centre $t_0$ in some open neighbourhood $U$ of $t_0$. Then the function is analytic at least on $U$.

Comment: Now, I see. Thank you all!